# Nodal Analysis wrong result

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, math, matrix, nodal-analysis

I'm trying to solve this problem, where I have to find the voltages v1 and v2.
This is the circuit:
[image: Circuit diagram]

This is what I came up with:
[image: Y-Matrix]

Then I calculated the inverse matrix using WolframAlpha.
[image: Inverse matrix]

Finally, this ended up being the result:
[image: Result calculation]

But the result is wrong, as v2 should be 2.45V and not 3V (as shown in the next diagram).
[image: simulation of the circuit]

So what did I do wrong here?
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all the answers.
The reason I use 3 equations and matrices is because I'm programming a program to solve circuits.
I created the example myself and recreated it in a [circuit simulator](https://mathonweb.com/nodal.htm). The resistance values are given in ohms.
When I calculate v2 the normal way, I get 2.4545V as the result.

[image: normal way of calculating v2]

That's why I don't understand why I get 3 as a result when doing it with matrices.

**EDIT 2**

Oh now I get it. I have to write the matrix like this:
[image: correct matrix]
That leads to:
[image]
with the result:
[image]

Comment: You got the right answer. Work out the KCL at V2 and you'll see you are right. It's really simple. \$v_2\cdot 2 + v_2\cdot 1+v_2\cdot 3= 9\cdot 2\$. This solves out as \$v_2=3\:\text{V}\$. No way around it. Geez. Who needs a matrix for this?

Comment: Why use a set of 3 equations?

Comment: g means conductance and its unit is siemens or mho.  If you want to calculate resistance it is \$\frac {1} {g} \$ . The rules are series conductances are calculated as parallel resistors. Parallel condutances are calculated as series resistors.  V * G = I is the conductance equation.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: @Leyonad So, you are working on a program and using nodal analysis. (I'm not sure, but perhaps you don't need any further help now?) I don't recall seeing any automated program (from SLIC or SPICE, 1970 onward) that uses resistance. Only conductance. So those 'g's I saw earlier I took to mean conductance (Siemens) and not resistance (Ohms.) In any case, the standard way to DC analysis is to just enumerate all of the non-zero nodes and place them into the node voltage vector. Your square matrix is the nodal *admittance* matrix. On the other side of the = sign is the current excitation vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the assumption that the resistor values are in siemens (hence the "g" designator) it can be redrawn in ohms like this: -

[image]

And, quite simply, V2 can be found thus: -

$$V_2 = 9\cdot\dfrac{R_2 || R_3}{R_1 + R_2 || R_3} = 9\cdot\dfrac{0.25}{0.75} = 3.0000\text{ volts}$$

If you assume the original diagram showed values in ohms, the voltage would be: -

$$2.4545\text{ volts}$$

In other words, you may need to try and figure out what the actual resistor units are.

Comment: It seems that the units are conductances or siemens. They dont seem as resistors. The problem may have  incorrect data.

Comment: @AmitM are you trying to suggest something new to my answer or just reiterating what I said but using different words?

Comment: I was saying that his book or problem had wrong data to have V2 = 2.45V . The components are siemens and your solution is correct to use them as resistors with values 1/g.

Comment: @AmitM please read these section [When should I comment and, when shouldn't I comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). I don't think your comment falls into a legal use.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: @Leyonad my answer remains the same. You need to find out whether the resistors are specified in ohms (resistance) or siemens (conductance). That is the reason why you see a difference.